# How do I safely get the internal path to the current site in a multisite setup?

Tags: theming, multi-sites

I'm working with a multisite Drupal 7 install with many sites. The site accepts both "www." and without via Apache. I'm developing a themes in /sites/all/themes which is used by many of these sites and I want something like this:

```
$apple_icon =  array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => '/' . path_to_site() . '/apple-touch-icon.png',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($apple_icon, 'apple-touch-icon');
```

where `path_to_site` gives like `/www/drupal7/sites/blah.com` etc. depending on the site being used. I need this since each site will need a different icon.

I guess something like `'/sites/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and then I can use symlink aliases for the "www." variant.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`conf_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path/7) to get the path root to the current site - then append the rest of your path to that.

> Returns the configuration path based on the site's hostname, port, and
>   pathname.

e.g:

```
$apple_icon =  array(
  '#tag' => 'link',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'href' => base_path() . conf_path() . '/apple-touch-icon.png',
    'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($apple_icon, 'apple-touch-icon');
```